# Creating custom validator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have validator, that validates one of fields on form. Field return value with class `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`

```
validate :begins_at_not_in_past

def begins_at_not_in_past
    return unless self.state == 'Scheduled'
    if self.begins_at != nil && self.begins_at < (Time.now - 1.hour)
       errors.add(:begins_at, 'Action cannot begin in past')
      false
    end

end
```

If validation fails it show me my error, however it does create new record in database even though data in form is not valid.
Where did i make mistake?

Comment: You should call begins_at_not_in_past in a `before_save` statement: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have following line. Otherwise it won't add error to object. So add following line with errors.add

```
validate :begins_at_not_in_past

def begins_at_not_in_past
  return unless self.state == 'Scheduled'
  if self.begins_at != nil && self.begins_at < (Time.now - 1.hour)
    errors.add(:begins_at, 'Action cannot begin in past')
    errors[:base] << 'Correct errors'  # Rails 2.3.X errors.add_to_base('msg')
    false
  end
end
```

In controller:      #Validation will run only when you call valid? method

```
if obj.valid?
  #do something
else
  flash[:error] = obj.errors.full_messages.join('<br/>')
end
```

Comment: do i need to specify field name?. Just tried, still added new record to database

Comment: you need to add both lines. add will highlight the field and add_to_base will be used to check errors. add_to_base won't take field name argument. It only displays the message.

Comment: still no luck. Got new record after adding this code. And you should user errors[:base]<< 'Your message'

Comment: no, i'm not checking, because i expected my model to reject new record.

Comment: Tried your way, but it does same as mine, creates new record even though validation failed

Comment: @sannySin you should use Callbacks (`before_save :begins_at_not_in_past` instead of `validates :begins_at_not_in_past`)

Answer (score 1):

In your model, try

```
validates :field_name, :begins_at_not_in_past => true
```

If you don't specify an acceptable return value from your validator the model may not consider it a failed validation.

Comment: getting "uknown validator" error with `validates :begins_at, :begins_at_not_in_past => true`

Comment: how have you defined the validator function? within a class that derives from ActiveModel::Validator or ActiveModel::EachValidator ?